# Requery Sub - Test is .value is set

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm struggling with the following pbm :

**PBM :**

I have a datasheet in SubForm - I would like to know if there is a way to know is .value is set or not.

When datasheet is empty I would like to Close the main form. Any possibility to get maybe the recordCount or something?

**Bad solution :**

I assume query count after I requery the subform

**Some tests :**

```
 If Me!SubStockEdit!DSIdStock Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Nothing"
Else
    Debug.Print "something"
    If IsEmpty(Me!SubStockEdit!DSIdStock) Then
            Debug.Print "Empty"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not Empty"
        If IsNull(Me!SubStockEdit!DSIdStock) Then
            Debug.Print "null"
        Else
            Debug.Print "not null"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

I tested the object but as supposed can't access .value which isn't set and the above returns `something Not Empty not null`.

Thanks in advance,
Falt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check if a form has no records is its CurrentRecord property. It is only 0 if the form is empty.

```
If Me!SubStockEdit.Form.CurrentRecord = 0 Then
    Debug.print "Empty!"
End If
```

Comment: Oh great. Didn't expect form had the method. I suppose that'll do it. Thx.